# '@storybook/addon-interactions' Is there a way to turn off autoplay of interactions?

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon

I want to use '@storybook/addon-interactions' v7.4.0 for some testing. However, I don't want the interactions to run automatically. The reason: The project I am working on will be visible to other parties. I don't want them distracted by the interactions running.
https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/ui-testing-handbook/react/en/interaction-testing/

I have tried to find a place to set autoplay: false, but nothing seems to work. I had it in the preview.js, main.js, in the story as a parameter, etc...  I am not sure if it is even a prop or parameter that can be set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
export const Basic: Story = {
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      story: { autoplay: true },
    },
  },
};
```

See:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/a3cdabb025524822807318bc137f69be006596c2/docs/snippets/web-components/api-doc-block-story-parameter.ts.mdx#L17